# Restricting ipaddress to access webservices

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat6

I have below 3 services and should let 3 different ipaddress to access them, please help me to sort out this

getJoinDate
getEmpCode
getEmpSal

```
@Controller
public class EmpRESTService {   

    @RequestMapping(value = "/Emp/getJoinDate", produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<?> getJoinDate(@RequestBody EmpJoinREST joinDateBody){
    //Code
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/Emp/getEmpCode", produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<?> getEmpCode(@RequestBody EmpCodeREST empCodeBody){
    //Code
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/Emp/getSal", produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<?> getEmpSal(@RequestBody EmpSal empSalBody){
    //Code
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Web.config ipSecurity**

The `web.config` file can be used to restrict website access, by the client IP address. `Web.config` can be used to restrict access to a single page, a directory and all sub directories, or even the entire web site. You can block all IP addresses and only let a few trusted IP addresses in, or you could allow everyone and block specific IP addresses or subnets.

While some `web.config` sections require that the containing directory is set as an application, this isn't one of them. A simple `web.config` with a `ipSecurity` section may be placed in any directory, and the directory does NOT need to be set as an application.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="true">    <!-- this line blocks everybody, except those listed below -->                
           <clear/> <!-- removes all upstream restrictions -->
           <add ipAddress="83.116.19.53"/>   <!-- block one IP  -->                
           <add ipAddress="83.116.119.0" subnetMask="255.255.255.0"/>   <!--block network 83.116.119.0 to 83.116.119.255-->               
        </ipSecurity>
      </security>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you Mr Saket!!!my requirement is not blocking entire site, it should do for individual web services.Ex:getJoinDate -allowed only for 10.*.*.*
getEmpCode - allowed only for 17.*.*.*
getEmpSal - allowed only for 201.*.*.*  like that